# determine convergence of complex set ∑ ln(n) / sinh(in)

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Determine if the series is convergent
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac {\ln n} { \sinh (in)}$$

I am stuck here guys, any hint? :/
I have tried abel test, but it didn't help.
Edit: Jose reminded me to check the main part's limit, which isn't zero.

Comment: What are you stuck on?

Comment: I tried every me known method, like Abel test, but in the answer shown below, I didn't have to go that deep :D

Comment: For some basic information about writing math at this site see e.g. [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It diverges, since you don't have $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\ln n}{\sinh(in)}=0$. In fact$$\left|\frac{\ln n}{\sinh(in)}\right|=\left|\frac{\ln n}{i\sin n}\right|=\left|\frac{\ln n}{\sin n}\right|\geqslant\ln n.$$